# Stopped - Too many triggering error Tradingview . Why is this happening?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, strategy-pattern

In the strategy I created; This is how the Strategy Login and Exit alarms fail.

How can I solve this problem? The strategy uses pyramiding.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWBVn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5cwf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CIEl.png)

Comment: You need to post a minimal reproducible example (in the question body, as text)

Answer (score -1):

This error trigger if the alert you set manually on the right of your trading view chart trigger many times in a short period of time.

In your case, your alert trigger 10 time in less than a minute => tradingview switch off your alert and send you an error message.

For example if your alert trigger on each bar and your chart timeframe is on 10 seconds, you will get this error after several alerts.

To avoid this error, you should design your alert so that it will trigger less often.